Is it possible to create custom gitlab quick action?
My requirement is to create a custom Gitlab quick action named say 'test_action'.  When user types /test_action and presses submit, then I need to invoke a web service and pass the data.
I am not sure whether it is possible in Gitlab?
I have come across quick actions documentation
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/quick_actions.html
But it does not have anything for my requirement.
Thanks in advance
